# Showing aux file after compiling

Tags: vim, vim-latex

I am using latex-suite for vim. A recent problem I come into is, after compiling the tex file, the original window showing tex is replaced by the aux file. 
Is there a way to stop this behavior and make vim keeps showing the original tex file from which I issued the compile command?

Comment: Is this happening because the first warning/error points to a line in the `.aux` file or under other circumstances?